# Math.ceil requires float

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

I am trying to round a float up using `Math.ceil()` but it keeps giving me the error "required: float, found: double". The problem is though that all of the variables are defined as floats. What can I do to make this work? the line looks like this:

```
perU30F = Math.ceil((under30FY / totalWatchers) * 100);
```

where `perU30F`, `under30FY` and `totalWatchers` are all defined as floats

Comment: You aren't even using `Math.ceil` in your code you have shown.

Comment: sorry that was an old part i'll edit it

Comment: This code should compile (http://ideone.com/cVOCiu).  Please create a proper test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't *calling* `Math.ceil` - it's using the *result* of it. `Math.ceil` returns a `double`, which can't be implicitly converted to `float`. You could cast it though:

```
perU30F = (float) Math.ceil((under30FY / totalWatchers) * 100);
```

Or you could just use `double` everywhere instead of `float` :)

(`Math.round` has an overload which accepts and returns `float`; `Math.ceil` doesn't.)